# question about conditional probability and $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-analysis

I have a question:

Given a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ and two random variables $X$ and $Y$. For a Borel-measurable set $\Gamma$, if there exists a measurable function $g$ such that

$$\mathbb{P}(X\in\Gamma|Y=y)=g(y),\ \ \mathbb{P\cdot Y^{-1}}\text{ -a.s}$$

Could we conclude that $\mathbb{P}(X\in\Gamma|Y)=g(Y)$? I believe the answer is yes. But how can we prove rigorously? I think Dynkin System theorem works if we can show $\sigma(\{Y=y\}, y\in\mathbb{R})$ can generate $\sigma(Y)$.

Many thanks!

Comment: How do you interpret $E[X \mid Y=y]$?  On its face, this expression only makes sense for those $y$ such that $\mathbb{P}(Y=y) > 0$, and in general there need not be any such $y$.

Comment: Thanks for your remark, this is a affirmation in page 75 of the book Brownian motion and Stochastic Calculus.

Comment: Do you mean the one by Karatzas and Shreve?  You should be able to find what they mean by this notation.  But in fact, $E[X \mid Y = y]$ is often *defined* as $g(y)$ for some function $g$ such that $E[X \mid Y] = g(Y)$.  It's not hard to show that such $g$ exists and is unique up to $P \circ Y^{-1}$-a.e. equality.

Comment: Also it looks like $P$ and $E$ are mixed up in several places in your question.  You may want to proofread.

Comment: Yes, this is a proposition of this book, but I want to know how to show rigorously $\mathbb{P}(X\in\Gamma|Y)=g(Y)$, could you give some indication? Many thanks!

Comment: It is a terrible notation!!! I would love if people dropped it...

Comment: To prove rigorously you need to start with rigorous definitions.